# Files with big size under the root folder

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I try to free space on my linux mint. For this, I executed the following command:

```
sudo find / -type f -size +500000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
```

I was surprised to see big files under the `root` folder with names starting with `tmp`:

```
/root/tmpi7zlWeEefGkTSKgkNx.OwOwu6riUIxJ0zERi9Vc-kmlVqi2FOTgcghzEavlS2rYiOk8ueIWwZ2tSwFf4EGlrYxmYkqVsAGfYUWhB6YWB5sMZKPkudzaJg1mf_woU.5fkfAN1vNCqmQQeoKHEPX7liBKfCXEMRvq3WmymdjKZG: 663M
/root/tmpv5wRjTFTVDJTdQpQg01TELoSFR2n7h9hOtR7TzZsrFggZ-yId691drlhY3m-w40KCnf_ktA1xuMc3ySuV5T1sSBxXdwLIYVtes0I6pFLxkEXwi4qb0SHku2q.mTz7A0dVs.w4C7N3nMlhqsLamb5l-ZbjqVIuI0MtJwPRYEnQczMe-ZmmnmG67B11OEzALpPhYDy3e: 2.0G
/root/tmp9ZSjQGbxfUS0EEgO3slimCl54bX9jv-GgNUGbb0SDV2TIcjy2q7f0yVfgD-af8JwUgmX4DFrtEmGlFtIS65_7aWxt.k7YfMvgAir66kse1shiT5mgfp7JN9nbb6T5VzDc_loWJSku0y1VAvy498nA1opRGfGA6Spg40afYTtYuwC9i0oObPpXI-VeTYyjT465ZHxZ0mbpJJs4T4abzYYhCIxImX3HoNlbL8WSUtwFVySIZkHzbQyppmKZNv: 1.6G
/root/tmpYkGr4ZI2ru2sk4xc: 906M
(...)
```

What do these files match? Can these files be deleted safely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the file command to see what type of files they are, and if they're non-binary, read them with tail/head/more/less etc. Don't use cat as that will just scroll too far since they're so large.

If they're text files, they should compress fairly well using tar. Create a tar file `tar -czvf tmp.tar tmp*`. This will give you a backup of these files in case they're needed. Once the tar file is created, you can delete the files and watch for any abnormal behavior.

If additional temp files are created, you can use auditctl to watch the /root directory and determine which processes are writing the files.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be temporary files so you can delete but i think should check the content of those files using head/tail command for some lines so it would be clear for you to identify how they are created and what it contains.